# How do I change font-awesome icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have a number of `nav` elements as shown below:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Job Title<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Add New</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">View / Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Inactive List</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It shows closed folder icon when I have that item both collapsed or open.

[image: Nav Image]

When clicked on the title to expand, I want it to change to `fa-folder-open` and when clicked again to close it, I want it to change to `fa-folder`. Since there are many such `nav` items, it should affect only the one that's being clicked.

Which event and on which element (in jQuery) is best to support this in all browsers?

Comment: Put both icons in there, and use a class on the parent `<li>` to indicate whether it's open or closed. Then use CSS to hide one `<i>` or the other based on the state of the menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbutton').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.fa-folder,.fa-folder-open').toggleClass('fa-folder').toggleClass('fa-folder-open');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<li>
    <a href="#" class="navbutton"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Job Title<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Add New</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">View / Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Inactive List</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

---

If you want to close every folder icon when opening another menu point, you can use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbutton').click(function() {
    var currentFolder = $(this).find('.fa-folder,.fa-folder-open');
    var openFolders = $(this).parents('.mainList').find('.fa-folder-open');
    var currentFolderAlreadySwitched = false;

    // it goes through all the folder icons and toggles its classes. if the currently clicked icon is also part of this list, it should only be switched once (so it is flagged as already switched)
    openFolders.each(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-folder fa-folder-open');
        if($(this).get(0) === currentFolder.get(0)) {
            currentFolderAlreadySwitched = true;
        }
    });

    // if the current folder was open, it would already be closed by the code above. therefore, it would open it right again here (so skip it)
    if(!currentFolderAlreadySwitched) {
        currentFolder.toggleClass('fa-folder fa-folder-open');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="mainList">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="navbutton"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Job Title<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Add New</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">View / Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Inactive List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="navbutton"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Job Title<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Add New</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">View / Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Inactive List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="navbutton"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Job Title<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Add New</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">View / Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Inactive List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works perfect but I have multiple `li` items.  Let us says, I have another menu item "Department'.  When I click on Job Title, it expands and changes icon.  When I go to Department, it changes Department folder icon to open, closes Job Title group but doesn't change Job Title icon to folder close icon.

Comment: You probably already have listener's on those elements (something opens and closes your lists). The best way would be, to put the icon stuff in those listener functions too. So basically: Search for code which opens and closes the lists and add this code there.

Comment: @techspider If you don't want to use the existing listener's you can also use the code from the updated snippet above. It mainly goes up to the main `<ul>` and then down again to every `.fa-folder-open` to close it. It then opens only the clicked one.

Comment: I tried adding in the existing listener but somehow something is getting overwritten.  Your new code is so close to perfection.  It works changing other elements icons when a new menu item is clicked.  But, it doesn't work closing the same menu. If I expand Job Title and close Job Title by clicking it two times, it doesn't change self icon to close

Comment: I'll change it ;)

Comment: Yes, this is perfect.  I have never used `parents` so far.  Learnt something awesome today.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could try doing that using the **.toggleClass** method. Doing it in a way suggested by Nicolas would be rather clumsy since you would need additional code to change them back again and *toggle* is much more semantically correct in this context.

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-folder fa-folder-open');
});
```

Comment: I kept it on onload, but this event never gets called.

Comment: You would need to customise it for your own HTML a little. Try changing the $('li a') part or have a look at ssc-hrep3's answer. He has got the code snippet there so you can try it out.

Answer (score 3):

you can change the class of the element and it will change the icon. For example, you can do something like this :

```js
$('.firstMenuItem').on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-folder').addClass('fa-folder-open');
  // rest of the code
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="firstMenuItem"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Job Title<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
```

Comment: You'd need to add something to remove `fa-folder-open` and replace with `fa-folder` when "open" nav item is clicked to go back to "closed" visual state.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky that's what I did, is there an error in my code ?

Comment: what is the class `navbutton`?

Comment: @techspider it's the li button. give me a second i'll try to edit my answer.

Comment: @Nicolas, there would need to be a check inside the `click` event handler to see whether the menu is opened or closed. If closed, it should remove `fa-folder` and add `fa-folder-open`. If open, it should remove `fa-folder-open` and add `fa-folder`. The code shown right now will never handle the situation of the menu going from open to closed. The user would click on the menu item, the menu would close, and it would still show and "open" folder icon.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky indeed it would be great but it's not our job to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery: 
JS Bin Link: http://jsbin.com/razaxis
Thanks to @ssc-hrep3 example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li ul').hide();
  $('.navbutton').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
    $(this).find('.fa-folder,.fa-folder-open').toggleClass('fa-folder').toggleClass('fa-folder-open');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="navbutton"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Job Title<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Add New</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">View / Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Inactive List</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="navbutton"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-fw"></i> Job Title<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Add New</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">View / Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Inactive List</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
  </ul>
```